# JAVA Appending stringbuilder to textarea, not replacing textarea just adding to it (need to replace instead of adding)

Tags: java, string, append, textarea, stringbuilder

I have a stringbuilder to load up some lists of strings, my problem is when I add to the textarea I want to replace what was there and not just add to it.. I'm posting all of my code which is a lot so I'll further explain if anyone needs additional information. I THINK the problem is when I convert the stringbuilder with the .toString() method when appending, that may be adding to the list each time and if that is the case I have no clue how to solve this...

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;


public class Lab10 extends JPanel
{
  private StringBuilder string, string2, string3, string4; //loads SuperStrings faster by appending all at once
  private JRadioButton occurrence, alphabetical;
  private JPanel text;
  private JComboBox<Integer> input;
  private JLabel label, file1,file2, unique, unique2;
  private JButton load, go,go2;
  private CountLinkedList<SuperString> words, words3; //Change impliments CountList to extends BinaryCountTree
  private OrderedLinkedList<SuperString> words2, words4;//Change impliments CountList to extends BinaryCountTree
  private String filename,filename2;
  private int width = 450;
  private int height = 550;
  private TextArea textarea,textarea2;
  Scanner scan;

  public Lab10()
  {
    string = new StringBuilder();
    string2 = new StringBuilder();
    string3 = new StringBuilder();
    string4 = new StringBuilder();
    ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener();
    Button2Listener listener2 = new Button2Listener();
    Integer [] select = {1,2,3,4};
    input = new JComboBox<Integer>(select);
    text = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
    go = new JButton("Select Text File 1: ");
    go2 = new JButton("Select Text File 2: ");
    label = new JLabel("N: " );
    unique = new JLabel("");
    unique2 = new JLabel("");
    file1 = new JLabel("");
    file1.setFont(new Font("Helvetica",Font.PLAIN,24));
    unique.setFont(new Font("Helvetica",Font.PLAIN,24));
    file2 = new JLabel("");
    file2.setFont(new Font("Helvetica",Font.PLAIN,24));
    unique2.setFont(new Font("Helvetica",Font.PLAIN,24));

    occurrence= new JRadioButton("Occurrence");
    occurrence.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_O);
    occurrence.addActionListener(listener);
    occurrence.addActionListener(listener2);
    occurrence.setSelected(true);


    alphabetical = new JRadioButton("Alphabetical");
    alphabetical.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    alphabetical.addActionListener(listener);
    alphabetical.addActionListener(listener2);

    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(occurrence);
    group.add(alphabetical);

    go.addActionListener(listener);
    go2.addActionListener(listener2);
    input.addActionListener(listener);
    input.addActionListener(listener2);

    textarea = new TextArea("",0,0,TextArea.SCROLLBARS_VERTICAL_ONLY);
    textarea2 = new TextArea("",0,0,TextArea.SCROLLBARS_VERTICAL_ONLY);
    textarea.setFont(new Font("Helvetica",Font.PLAIN,24));
    textarea2.setFont(new Font("Helvetica",Font.PLAIN,24));
    textarea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height));
    textarea2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height));
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000,700));
    text.add(textarea);
    text.add(textarea2);
    add(occurrence);
    add(alphabetical);
    add(label);
    add(input);
    add(go);
    add(file1);
    add(unique);
    add(go2);
    add(file2);
    add(unique2);

    add(text);

    textarea.setText("No File Selected");
    textarea2.setText("No File Selected");


  }
    public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener //makes buttons do things
    {
      JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("../Text");


      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
      {
       Integer N = input.getSelectedIndex()+1;

        if(event.getSource() == go)
      {

        int returnvalue = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

    if(returnvalue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
      try
      {
        File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        String text1= file.getName();
        file1.setText(text1);
        filename = file.getName();
        System.err.println(filename);
        scan = new Scanner(file);

      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
        System.err.println("IO EXCEPTION");
        return;
      }       
    }
    else
    {
      return;
    }


     String[] storage = new String[N];
    words = new CountLinkedList<SuperString>();
    words2 = new OrderedLinkedList<SuperString>();
   for(int i=1;i<N;i++)
     storage[i] = scan.next().toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "")
                  .replaceAll("[.,':]","");

    while(scan.hasNext())
    {
      for(int i=0;i<=N-2;i++)
        storage[i] = storage[i+1];
      storage[N-1] = scan.next().toLowerCase();
      storage[N-1] = storage[N-1].replace(",","").replace(".","").replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "")
                  .replaceAll("[.,':]","");
      SuperString ss = new SuperString(storage);
      SuperString ss2= new SuperString(storage);
      words.add(ss );
      words2.add(ss2 );
    }

    textarea.setText("");
        }
    SuperString[] ss = new SuperString[words.size()];
    SuperString[] ss2 = new SuperString[words2.size()];
    int i=0;
    int count =0, count2= 0;


    for(SuperString word: words)
    {
      ss[i] = word;
      i++;
    }
    int j=0;
    for(SuperString word: words2)
    {
      ss2[j] = word;
      j++;
    }


    Arrays.sort(ss, new SuperStringCountOrder());

    for(SuperString word : ss)
    {
      count++;
      string.append(Integer.toString(count)+ "       "+ word+ "\n");
    }
    if(occurrence.isSelected())
    {
      string.replace(0,0,"");
     textarea.setText("");
     textarea.append("    "+filename+" has wordcount: "+words.size()+
      "\n-------------------------\n\n");
     textarea.append(string.toString());
    }


     for(SuperString word : ss2)
    {
       count2++;
       string2.append(Integer.toString(count2)+ "       "+ word.toString()+ "\n");  
    }
         if(alphabetical.isSelected())
    {
                 string.replace(0,0,"");
      textarea.setText("");
      textarea.append("    "+filename+" has wordcount: "+words.size()+
      "\n-------------------------\n\n");
      textarea.append(string2.toString());

    }
     unique.setText("Unique Count: "+ Integer.toString(words.size()));

      }
    }


    public class Button2Listener implements ActionListener
    {
       JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("../Text");


      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
      {
       Integer N = input.getSelectedIndex()+1;

         if(event.getSource() == go2)
      {

        int returnvalue = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

    if(returnvalue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
      try
      {
        File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        String text2= file.getName();
        file2.setText(text2);
        filename2 = file.getName();
        System.err.println(filename);
        scan = new Scanner(file);

      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
        System.err.println("IO EXCEPTION");
        return;
      }       
    }
    else
    {
      return;
    }

     String[] storage = new String[N];
    words3 = new CountLinkedList<SuperString>();
    words4 = new OrderedLinkedList<SuperString>();
   for(int i=1;i<N;i++)
     storage[i] = scan.next().toLowerCase().replace(",","").replace(".","");

    while(scan.hasNext())
    {
      for(int i=0;i<=N-2;i++)
        storage[i] = storage[i+1];
      storage[N-1] = scan.next().toLowerCase();
      storage[N-1] = storage[N-1].replace(",","").replace(".","").replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "")
                  .replaceAll("[.,':]","");
      SuperString ss = new SuperString(storage);
      SuperString ss2= new SuperString(storage);
      words3.add(ss );
      words4.add(ss2 );
    }
    textarea2.setText("");
         }
    SuperString[] sstwo = new SuperString[words3.size()];
    SuperString[] ss2two = new SuperString[words4.size()];
    int i=0;
    int count =0, count2= 0;

    for(SuperString word2: words3)
    {
      sstwo[i] = word2;
      i++;
    }

    int j=0;
    for(SuperString word2: words4)
    {
      ss2two[j] = word2;
      j++;
    }  

    Arrays.sort(sstwo, new SuperStringCountOrder());

        for(SuperString word2 : sstwo)
    {
      count++;
      string3.append(Integer.toString(count)+ "       "+ word2+ "\n");
    }
    if(occurrence.isSelected())
    {
     textarea2.setText("");
     textarea2.append("    "+filename2+" has wordcount: "+words3.size()+
      "\n-------------------------\n\n");
     textarea2.append(string3.toString());
    }

     for(SuperString word2 : ss2two)
    {
       count2++;
        string4.append(count2+"   "+ "  "+word2+"\n");     
    }
     if(alphabetical.isSelected())
          {
       textarea2.setText("");
       textarea2.append("    "+filename2+" has wordcount: "+words3.size()+
      "\n-------------------------\n\n");
       textarea2.append(string4.toString());
       }

     unique2.setText("Unique Count: "+ Integer.toString(words3.size()));

      }
    }



   public static void main(String[] arg)
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Lab 10");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
    frame.getContentPane().add(new Lab10());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: is this code not replacing the text in text area?

Comment: Noooo and I have no idea whyyyy

Comment: textarea2.setText(""); textarea2.append(" "+filename2+" has wordcount: "+words3.size()+ "\n-------------------------\n\n"); textarea2.append(string4.toString()); is this the code appending the text instead of adding?

Comment: `JTextArea#setText`?

Comment: actually the only thing adding to it are the lists, so It's got to be the "textarea2.append(string4.toString());" bit.... the same goes for each of my lists

Comment: I'm assuming the problem is because I don't really understand stringbuilders or how to use them. lol

Comment: textarea.setText is not working but I may be adding to my stringbuilder with textarea2.append(string4.toString()); somehow?
 its the only thing I can think of that's happening

Comment: Append is going to add to whatever string is already there. textarea.setText(string) should get you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your "string" is a StringBuilder instance variable, and you never reset it. You do

```
textarea.setText("");
textarea.append(string.toString());
```

so you are clearing the textarea first as you wanted to. But the value of "string" only ever gets appended to as far as I can see. Are you trying to clear it with

```
string.replace(0,0,"");
```

on line 187 perhaps? That won't work. replace(0,0,"") won't replace anything. The second parameter needs to be the number of characters to replace. (Strictly speaking it's the index of the first character not to replace but in this case that amounts to the same thing.) The output of this might help clarify what it's doing.

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      sb.append("abcdefg");
      System.out.println("String is [" +sb + "]");
      sb.replace(0,0,"");
      System.out.println("String is [" +sb + "]");
      sb.replace(0,1000,"");
      System.out.println("String is [" +sb + "]");
    }
}
```

Output:

String is [abcdefg]

String is [abcdefg]

String is []

Comment: Okay so this works I did (string.replace(0,string.size(),""); .. this works BUT it prints out 2 lists unless I select occurrence or alphabetical twice then it goes down to one list. So my string.replace code isn't working until after it is selected twice...? If that makes sense

Comment: So initially it prints out 2 lists and after selecting button again it prints out 1 (which is what I want)

Comment: In general it's a good idea to declare variables in the closest scope to where you use them. You could have your  `string = new StringBuilder();` line inside the  `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)` method. Then you'd be sure it's reset / recreated each time the action happens. As it stands now it persists between clicks. Also, I think there's an error around line 200. That region of code is manipulating the string2 variable, but on that line you call the reset on string not string2.

Comment: One more little thing...the scroll bar scrolls all the way down when I load a list, anyway to get it to not scroll to the bottom automatically?

Comment: Once you've added the text you can do `textArea.setCaretPosition(0)` to set the insertion point back to the beginning of the text. I think the text area  will automatically scroll back to the top so that the insertion point is visible.